# How can I run nginx as an SSL reverse proxy and a web server simultaneously?

Tags: nginx, php

My SSL reverse proxy works fine but I can't figure out how to make nginx work as both an SSL proxy and web server for one PHP directory simultaneously.

```
server {
    listen 10.0.0.20:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 10.0.0.20:443 ssl http2 backlog=16384;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /home/ubuntu/example-ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /home/ubuntu/example-ssl/example.key;
    ssl_dhparam /home/ubuntu/example-ssl/dh2048.pem;  # unique for each site
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    add_header Public-Key-Pins 'pin-sha256="example-pin"; pin-sha256="example-backup-pin";  max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains';
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header  X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    access_log  off;

    location / {

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

    }
```

Above proxy is fine, but how can I serve a web app from /fusion at same time?

```
    location /fusion {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-sitename-example.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location /fusion/l/ {
        rewrite ^/l/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ /l.php?i=$1 last;
    }

    location /fusion/t/ {
        rewrite ^/t/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ /t.php?i=$1 last;
    }

    location /fusion/w/ {
        rewrite ^/w/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ /w.php?i=$1 last;
    }

    location /fusion/unsubscribe/ {
        rewrite ^/unsubscribe/(.*)$ /unsubscribe.php?i=$1 last;
    }

    location /fusion/subscribe/ {
        rewrite ^/subscribe/(.*)$ /subscribe.php?i=$1 last;
    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect you didn't get many replies because of first the time you posted, and second because your aim and problem wasn't clearly stated. It seems fairly trivial and unrelated to both terminate SSL and service multiple locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After puzzling over a lot of fastcgi "File not found errors" I was finally able to get it to work using the code below.

Appending this code to the already working reverse proxy allowed me to run a PHP app in the subdirectory of the primary domain.

```
    root /var/www/example;
    index index.php index.html;

    location /example {
      root /var/www/example;
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?$args;
      index index.php index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    }
```